# Why does IsList require toList?

Tags: haskell, overloaded-strings, overloaded-lists

When using `-XOverloadedStrings` you can implement `IsString` which only requires a function `fromString`.
Now *if* you want to use string literals for pattern matching, you also have to implement `Eq`, which makes sense:

```
f :: MyString -> Bool
f "foo" = True
f _ = False

-- equivalent to
f x
  | x == fromString "foo" = True
  | otherwise             = False
```

But then why does the `IsList` type class which is used with `-XOverloadedLists` require that you implement `toList`?
In the [wiki](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/overloaded-lists) the only mentioned use-case of `toList` is pattern matching.
And I get that `Eq` is not sufficient for list pattern matching.
But then `toList` should be in a different type class that's only required *if* you'd like to use list pattern matching with your type, just like `IsString` does not *require* `Eq`.

The annoying thing about this to me is that the condition `fromList . toList = id` has to be met but this simply can't be guaranteed for some types like e.g. an unordered collection which make no guarantees that the order of elements is kept.

This just seems very inconsistent.

Comment: Hysterical raisins, as they say.

Comment: I would personally argue that anything hijacking the list syntax should be isomorphic to built-in Haskell lists, hence should be ordered. If I ever saw `[1, 2, 3, 4]` in a context where the result of that expression was an unordered collection, I'd have some unfortunate words for the developer of that code

Answer (score 6):

What is overloaded in both extensions is merely a *notation*. The difference between the two notations is that a list can contain variables
(`[x, y]`) while strings cannot: Haskell doesn't do variable interpolation like `let x = "apple" in "I like {x} pie")`

This difference becomes important when I use either notation inside a pattern: I expect to be able to bind variables in a pattern like

```
f :: MyList Int -> Bool
f [x, y] = x > y
```

... while, even though  I can use string literals as a pattern

```
 f :: MyString -> Bool
 f "apple" = True
```

... those will never bind a variable

To see the difference this makes, suppose that `-XOverloadedLists` would translate pattern matches exactly like `-XOverloadedStrings`. The pattern match

```
f [x,y] = x > y
```

would be translated as

```
f z
 | z == fromList [x, y] = x > y
```

But `fromList [x, y]` *is not a constructor pattern*: for a given `z`, there may be *several different*  values for `x` and `y` such that `fromList [x, y] == z` (In your example, an unordered collection `{1, 2}` is equal to `fromList [1, 2]` but also to `fromList [2, 1]` - so should the result of `f {1, 2}` be `True` or `False`?

This shows that for pattern matching to work, `Mylist a` needs to be *isomorphic* to `[a]`, in other words, a `toList` is needed that satisfies the appropriate laws. We then can find the *unique* `x, y` such that `z == fromList [x, y]` by applying `toList` to `z`,  so the translation instead is

```
f z
 | toList z == [x, y] = x > y
```

Or, with a [view pattern](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/view-patterns) (which doesn't even need `Eq` anymore):

```
f (toList -> [x,y]) = x > y
```

So, ultimately, your `IsList` class without the `toList` would not allow overloaded list patterns, but still make it possible to denote your unordered collection `{1, 2}` using list notation `[1, 2]`. But then we would have `-XOverloadedLists` and `-XOverloadedListPatterns` - probably not worth the hassle.